# Access the variable of a fragment from a ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-fragmentactivity

I used the example that incorporates Android Studio to make an example of a NavigationDrawer in Android. I made some small modifications to the code to perform various operations from the main activity.

```js
package ugr.mohabb.navigationdrawerexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**dsf* Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private int sectionSelected;
    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

        this.sectionSelected=position;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment;
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                    fragment=new PlaceholderFragment("Section 1");
                    // I want to acces to variable Example, I try:
                    break;
            case 1:
                    fragment=new PlaceholderFragment("Section 2");
                    break;
            case 2:
                    fragment=new PlaceholderFragment( "Section 3");
                    break;
            default:
                    fragment=new PlaceholderFragment("Default");
                    break;

        }

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        private String Example;
        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment("Default");
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment( String Example) {
            this.Example=Example;
        }

        public String getExample() {
            return Example;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

I modified the Fragment to incorporate a String as an argument to the constructor.

```js
 private String Example;
        public PlaceholderFragment( String Example) {
            this.Example=Example;
        }
```

In the ActivityMain I added a switch to different operations :

```js
@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

        this.sectionSelected=position;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment;
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                    fragment=new PlaceholderFragment("Section 1");
                    // I want to acces to variable Example??
                    break;
            case 1:
                    fragment=new PlaceholderFragment("Section 2");
                    break;
            case 2:
                    fragment=new PlaceholderFragment( "Section 3");
                    break;
            default:
                    fragment=new PlaceholderFragment("Default");
                    break;

        }

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

My question is, how do i could access to the methods and variables of the  Fragment extends class from the activity?

Thanks,

Comment: so you mean methods inside the Placeholder class?

Comment: Yes, the method, getExample(){ return this.Example;} in the Fragment classs

Comment: You need to use an interface to pass information from your fragment to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

When user selects a list item from navigation drawer, we need to display respected view in the main view. This can be done by adding a list item click listener and loading respected fragment view in the call back event.

Sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
..
..
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

     /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, please refer to [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).

Comment: I have visited that page several times and provides much information on the subject but does not solve my doubt . My idea is that each fragment has in it a   XYPlot variable  of the AndroidPlot Library  and a String variable  as title. I want to access these objects from the MainActivity to modify it. how i could  do this ?

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment, declare the interface...

```
public interface OnDataPass {
    public void onDataPass(String data);
}
```

Then, connect the containing class implementation of the interface to the fragment in the onAttach method, like so:

```
OnDataPass dataPasser;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity a) {
    super.onAttach(a);
    dataPasser = (OnDataPass) a;
}
```

Within your fragment, when you need to handle the passing of data, just call it on the dataPasser object:

```
public void passData(String data) {
    dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
}
```

Finally, in your containing activity which implements OnDataPass...

```
@Override
public void onDataPass(String data) {
    Log.d("LOG","hello " + data); // or whatever
}
```